# How to write SQL query into code-igniter formate

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How to write below SQL query in to code-igniter

```
SELECT 
    `pm`.`id`, 
    `pm`.`region`,
    `pm`.`port_name`,
    `pm`.`country`,
    `tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`YEAR`,
    `tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`TOTAL_THROUGHPUT`,
    `tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`status`
    FROM (`tbl_port_annual_throughput`) 
    JOIN `port_master` pm 
      ON `pm`.`id` = `tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`PORT_ID` 
    WHERE `pm`.`country` = "100@Kenya" 
    AND (
        (`tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`YEAR` =  '2014' AND `tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`status` =  'Confirmed') 
        OR (`tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`YEAR` =  '2015' AND `tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`status` =  'Confirmed')
        OR (`tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`YEAR` =  '2016' AND `tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`status` =  'Confirmed')
    )
```

Comment: Just use `$this->db->query("YOUR_QUERY_HERE");` [Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$or_where= "(`tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`YEAR` =  '2014' AND `tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`status` =  'Confirmed') OR (`tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`YEAR` =  '2015' AND `tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`status` =  'Confirmed') OR (`tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`YEAR` =  '2016' AND `tbl_port_annual_throughput`.`status` =  'Confirmed')";

            $this->db->select('pm.id, pm.region,pm.port_name,pm.country,tbl_port_annual_throughput.YEAR,tbl_port_annual_throughput.TOTAL_THROUGHPUT,tbl_port_annual_throughput.status');
            $this->db->join('port_master as pm','pm.id = tbl_port_annual_throughput.PORT_ID');
            $this->db->where('pm.country','100@Kenya');
            $this->db->where($or_where);
            return $this->db->get('tbl_port_annual_throughput')->result();
```

Comment: i also need all status condition year wise not common

Comment: your query in the question giving right answer? have you checked it?

Comment: what should you need in result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query builder class:

```
$this->db->select
$this->db->from
$this->db->join
```

These kinds of methods can be used to do the same as you want in your query

You can find more here: [Linkylink](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: yes I have tried many things but i have problem in where conditions

Answer (score 0):

Well before you can convert this, the actual SQL needs a bit of a tidy up...

```
SELECT 
    `pm`.`id`, 
    `pm`.`region`,
    `pm`.`port_name`,
    `pm`.`country`,
    `pat`.`YEAR`,
    `pat`.`TOTAL_THROUGHPUT`,
    `pat`.`status`
    FROM `tbl_port_annual_throughput` pat 
    JOIN `port_master` pm 
      ON `pm`.`id` = `pat`.`PORT_ID` 
    WHERE `pm`.`country` = "100@Kenya" 
    AND `pat`.`YEAR` IN ('2014','2015','2016')
    AND `pat`.`status` =  'Confirmed'
```

So now it is simpler and works - tested in a quick simulation of your tables...

NOTE: Just make sure the above actually does work for you first.

Have a go at converting that.

Comment: But i have to satisfy all condition like all years and all status parallelly

Comment: "But i have to satisfy all condition like all years and all status parallelly" That is exactly what its doing. You only need to qualify the status once. If an item is not "Confirmed" it won't get selected. it does Exactly what your original query does. I am not sure why you insist you need to test it repeatedly for every year!

Answer (score 0):

if you really want your exact query you can do something like this

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('pm.id, pm.region, pm.port_name, tbl_port_annual_throughput.YEAR, tbl_port_annual_throughput.TOTAL_THROUGHPUT, tbl_port_annual_throughput.status')
    ->from('tbl_port_annual_throughput')
    ->join('port_master pm', 'pm.id = tbl_port_annual_throughput.PORT_ID')
    ->where('pm.country','100@Kenya')
    ->group_start()
        ->group_start()
            ->where('tbl_port_annual_throughput.YEAR','2014')
            ->where('tbl_port_annual_throughput.status','Confirmed')
        ->group_end()
        ->or_group_start()
            ->where('tbl_port_annual_throughput.YEAR','2015')
            ->where('tbl_port_annual_throughput.status','Confirmed')
        ->group_end()
        ->or_group_start()
            ->where('tbl_port_annual_throughput.YEAR','2016')
            ->where('tbl_port_annual_throughput.status','Confirmed')
        ->group_end()
    ->group_end()
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this query

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('pm.id, pm.region, pm.port_name, tbl_port_annual_throughput.YEAR, tbl_port_annual_throughput.TOTAL_THROUGHPUT, tbl_port_annual_throughput.status')
    ->from('tbl_port_annual_throughput')
    ->join('port_master pm', 'pm.id = tbl_port_annual_throughput.PORT_ID')
    ->where('pm.country','100@Kenya')
    ->group_start()
        ->group_start()
            ->where('tbl_port_annual_throughput.YEAR','2014')
            ->where('tbl_port_annual_throughput.status','Confirmed')
        ->group_end()
    ->group_end()
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $wherearraydata1 = array('tbl_port_annual_throughput.YEAR' => '2014', 'tbl_port_annual_throughput.status' => 'Confirmed');
    $wherearraydata2 = array('tbl_port_annual_throughput.YEAR' => '2015', 'tbl_port_annual_throughput.status' => 'Confirmed');
    $wherearraydata3 = array('tbl_port_annual_throughput.YEAR' => '2016', 'tbl_port_annual_throughput.status' => 'Confirmed');


    $this->db->select('pm.id,pm.region,pm.port_name,pm.country,tbl_port_annual_throughput.YEAR,tbl_port_annual_throughput.TOTAL_THROUGHPUT,tbl_port_annual_throughput.status');
    $this->db->from('tbl_port_annual_throughput');
    $this->db->join('port_master', 'port_master.id = tbl_port_annual_throughput.PORT_ID');
    $this->db->where('pm.country','100@Kenya');        
    $this->db->where("( $wherearraydata1 OR $wherearraydata2 OR $wherearraydata3)");        
    $querydata = $this->db->get();

    return $querydata->result_array();
```